# componentDidUpdate error is React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops how to fix this issue

Tags: reactjs

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
 componentDidMount() {
this.setState({
  form_items: this.props.form_items,
});
console.log(this.props.form_items, this.props.init_values);
}
```

Comment: It is likely a programming error in your component. If you share more code from your component it will be possible to help more.

Comment: You are probably calling `setState` within it without any conditions? Please show us the full code though

Comment: Please add your relevant code

Comment: can you check this code

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      form_items: this.props.form_items,
    });
    console.log(this.props.form_items, this.props.init_values);

    // if (this.props.init_values) {
    //   this.bindInitFormValues(this.props.init_values);
    //  // console.log()
    // }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, Props) {
    if (this.props.init_values) {
      this.bindInitFormValues(this.props.init_values);
      // console.log()
    }

    this.handleAddBreederActionData(this.props.addBreedMomActionData);
  }

Comment: It's bad idea to call setState in componentDidUpdate without any if statemenet. Besides that you can set this.state.form_items = {...props.form_items} in class constructor, instead of calling setState in componentDidMount to set initial state. Please add more code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must note that componentDidUpdate is called on state as well as props change. Now when you write a login in componentDidUpdate which sets state based on prop change, you must always add a comparison between previous and currentProps otherwise it would trigger an infinite loop

In your case you can write it like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.init_values !== preProps.init_values) {
    this.bindInitFormValuesUpdate(this.props.init_values);
  }
    console.log(this.props.init_values,this.props.form_items);
  if(this.props.addBreeMomActionData !== prevProps.addBreedMomActionData) {
    this.handleAddBreederActionData(this.props.addBreedMomActionData);
  }
}
```

Also the arguments to `componentDidUpdate` are `prevProps` and `prevState` and not `(nextProps, props)`

Also if you are changing references of `addBreedMomActionData` and `init_values` from parent even when you are not updating you might need to perform a deepEqual comparison

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(!_isEqual(this.props.init_values,preProps.init_values)) {
    this.bindInitFormValuesUpdate(this.props.init_values);
  }
    console.log(this.props.init_values,this.props.form_items);
  if(!_.isEqual(this.props.addBreeMomActionData,prevProps.addBreedMomActionData)) {
    this.handleAddBreederActionData(this.props.addBreedMomActionData);
  }
}
```

P.S. In the above code `_.isEqual` is used from `lodash` or `underscore` libraries. You can implement your own version if you like

Comment: As I said, you might need to make a deep equality check

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.something !== prevProps.something) {
    doSomething;
  }
}
```

You are not comparing the props, don't forget to compare props